# Using a Loop to Pair Indexes in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, formatting, std-pair

Please be patient. I'm new to Python and only 1 month in. In this proect, I import a file that simulates a list of names with associated scores. I'm having a hard time creating a loop that will print out the 1st index and its associated pair. My program needs to
divide the player list in half, and generate pairs using a player from each half of the list. For  example, if there are 10 players sorted by rating, player 1 plays player 6, 2 plays 7, etc.

Can someone give me a quick guide into the correct direction? My sample code is below, which once completed, I will need to make this into a program with working functions.

```
def main():

    myfile = open('CHESS.txt','r')

    players = []

    for line in myfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        players.append(line)
        players.sort()


    for i in players:
        m=len(players)/2
        print(players[0], players[0+m])


    myfile.close()

main()
```

Comment: a cool trick to use here is `zip(players,players[len(players)/2:])`

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just need to use an index `i` for each element in your list.

```
m=len(players)/2
for i in range(m):
    print(players[i], players[i+m])
```

Note that this requires you have an even number of players.

Comment: This is very close! I'm glad I was going in the right direction! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When I'm writing this code, its coming back to as an error.  * float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer* how do i convert the list from a float to an interger as stated in the error message?

Comment: Are you running the code exactly as I pasted it? I don't think you should be getting that error. It works on my machine using Python2.7.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.2. It's coming back as:  line 14, in main
    for i in range(m):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: afaik you need to use `len(players)//2` since py3x returns floats on normal division

Comment: everyone! thank you for all your help/support. i was able to run my program and it was successful :)

Answer (score 1):

Classic use case for `zip`:

```
>>> players = ["Player{}".format(i) for i in range(20)]
>>> half = len(players)/2
>>> pairs = zip(players[:half], players[half:])
>>> pairs
[('Player0', 'Player10'), ('Player1', 'Player11'), ('Player2', 'Player12'), ('Player3', 'Player13'), ('Player4', 'Player14'), ('Player5', 'Player15'), ('Player6', 'Player16'), ('Player7', 'Player17'), ('Player8', 'Player18'), ('Player9', 'Player19')]
```

Comment: afaik you dont need to limit the first names in the zip ... since zip will end on the shorter result (eg you can just do `zip(names,names[half:])`

Comment: Good point, thanks, didnt think of that. But I still prefer the explicit way, as the intention is more obvious there.